# Comma before "that"

Tags: punctuation

Came across a sentence:

> Among their findings was that residents of cities apparently have a lower risk of psychological problems when they have regular access to a park or other natural environment, that has the effect of reducing the level of stress hormones

It's a writing test,and this was marked as the "correct" answer. I'm having trouble justifying the comma in front of "that". I'd like to know whether it is a rule I've never heard of or just a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that you’ve written

> other natural environment, **that** has the effect

Except that we cannot use *that* there at all. This is one of those “real”* places where you cannot freely interchange *that* and *which*.  You need *which* here because it is **not** a restrictive/defining clause:

> other natural environment, **which** has the effect

Descriptive/non-defining clauses like these require *which*, never *that*.

---

<sub>* “Real” in that this a matter of grammar not of style advice, the latter of which often tries to pretend that you should follow its stylistic preferences as though they were actual grammatical rules.</sub>

Comment: I originally thought that the "that has the effect..." part refered to the "environment".So would it be correct if it was the case?

Comment: @DwightSchrute To, it’s referring to “when they have regular access to a park or other natural environment”.

Comment: Good answer. I do not understand why anyone would down-vote it. (Your answer does not require the word "real," however, and the  footnote is also unnecessary. I don't like to edit other people's answers, especially ones by someone as learned and experienced as you, or I would remove them myself.) +1.